# Using regular expression to match decimal range

Tags: regex

How do I formulate this as a regular expression

```
if (a > 0 and a < 50)
  Match
else
  NoMatch
```

Where `a` is a decimal value with `.` as decimal separator.

I am aware that I would be easier off using the code above, but unfortunately I have to do it as a regular expression.

Comment: Is this for school?

Comment: Why do you have to do it as a regex? That's probably the worst possible solution. How do you write a regex that will validate 1.7685939828892840293480283420834, which would fit into the description of your requirements? What about all of the digits of pi, which would also fit within that range? Did your teacher tell you it had to be a regular expression?

Comment: This is for an argument in a component that does validation based on the regular expression and complains if the entered value does not match the regular expression. I do not have the abiltiy to handle this validation outside unfortunately even though it would be heaps easier

Comment: So no, it is not for school :-)

Comment: So a) validate it before passing it to the component, and then provide the actual value as your regex; b) find a different component; or c) refine your requirements so that a reasonable regex would work, and then at least show your efforts here to try to write a regex that would work. We're not a *Here's a vague description of what I need. Could a regex monkey crank out an expression that will work for me?* site. You've not even bothered to make an attempt; you haven't even specify which one of the many varied regex engines you're using, which is extremely relevant to any answer.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggested solutions?

Comment: The solution from dawg works as a charm. I will need to modify it so that it doesn't necessarily require a period, but I am sure that now I have a direction, that will not be an issue.

Comment: With respect to the comment from Ken White, I find your tone inappropriate and I will not spend time arguing against you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I endorse using a regex for this, but you can do:

```
^(?=[0.]*[1-9])((?:0|1|2|3|4)[0-9]?\.(?:\d*))$
```

[Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/4SWdPD/2)

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: I guess now it depends on use-case... Your answer is minimalistic, simple to follow, and provides the whole match as a single group; while mine is a mess of groupings and `OR`s, but separates each part of the string into groups representing the components, such as leading zeroes, and pre- and post- decimal-point digits, being ready for `Pattern-Matcher` structures handling data in specific groups rather than the whole thing. =)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did visit the site you are referring to, but failed finding an answer to my question. Ill give it another chance :-)

Comment: Oh, your answer doesn't handle more than 1 leading `0`, as can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/sTyZ9H/1). Adding a `*` or `+` after the zero on `(?:0|1|2|3|4)` fixes it, as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/1dCfu0/1) - Should be a minor issue, so I'll maintain my +1 - EDIT: Just making sure @FranzThomsen, who just accepted answer, is aware that this minor fix is needed. =)

Comment: Yes, got it :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: @FranzThomsen:   I am not sure that multiple leading was specified or important.

Answer (score 1):

My take:

`^(0+((\.)0*[1-9]\d*))|(0*(([1-4]\d)|[1-9])((\.)\d+)?)$`

Comment: This matches 50. The OP states `a > 0 and a < 50`. Also matches 0.0

Comment: @dawg Oh, you're right! And it shouldn't match `0(.0+)` either! Sorry, my slip-up! Fixing...

Comment: @dawg Should be fixed now. If you down-voted, please revert. =)